# Syntax highlighting for Markdown?

Tags: javascript, markdown, syntax-highlighting

The only highlighter that seems to do it is the famous Highlight.JS one. But is that really true?

I want to build a minimalistic editor that has syntax highlighting for markdown. However, I can not seem to find a good highlighter for Markdown, not to mention GFM...

So my simple question: Does syntax highlighting for markdown even exist? Because the one from Highlight.JS is extremely basic - I have seen it only highlighting headers, at all.

Comment: You will probably find better results looking at text editors and/or IDEs. Of course, their highlighting engines won't be of much help as a JS lib, but you can see more options for how Markdown text can be highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: [Yes, it exists.](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/sublime-markdown-extended) [There are a few options, actually.](https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing)

To solve your problem: [There's a CodeMirror option for you](https://codemirror.net/mode/markdown/). Actually this option is probably your best bet.

Comment: I am trying to avoid CodeMirror because of its enormous size (iirc 200kb minified/gzipped). But thanks anyway, I'll see if these two ST plugins help :)

Comment: Understandable. So are you trying to make something new?

Comment: Yep. Just a small Editor you can drop on your app to give users a basic Markdown editor that gets the job done and isn't ultimatively big. Basic idea: http://sjonhortensius.github.io/LRTEditor/ - might fork that one to have a solid base. But I am missing the highlighter part so far :)